# Create Web Client Solution dialog closes on click or tab out of default field without messages

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008

I installed Web Client Software Factory February 2008 release on Visual Studio Team System 2008 Development Edition (without SP1). When I first installed that, I tried out the software factory as I've never used one before and it worked fine. That was two months ago.

Recently I needed to learn how to use the software factory and when I tried to create a WCSF solution, I get a problem.

The WCSF shows up as a Visual Studio installed template under the Guidance Package project type. There are four templates (which I believe is as it should be) which are:

- Web Client Solution (C#, Web Site)
- Web Client Solution (C#, WAP)
- Web Client Solution (Visual Basic, Web Site)
- Web Client Solution (Visual Basic, WAP)

Once I select any of them and proceed to create the solution, Visual Studio displays the 'Create Web Client Solution' dialog. Here's the weird part. As long as I click on any clickable control e.g. TextBox, Button or I press the 'Tab' key on the keyboard to change the cursor's location, the dialog just closes, no solution is created and the status bar will display "Creating project 'C:\MyWebApp' ... project creation failed." If I click on any other part of the dialog, nothing happens.

I've tried uninstalling everything (including Visual Studio) and reinstall and it still won't work. I tried using Microsoft's 'Windows Install Clean Up' tool to ensure any potential corrupt MSI entries are removed before reinstalling. Nothing works.

Hopefully someone else has faced this before and found an answer.

Cheers.

~ hg

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might be a VS related authorization problem not a particular WCFS problem.
Try this fix:
http://developerspoint.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/how-to-deal-with-project-creation-failed-problem-of-visual-studio-2008/

Comment: farside, thanks for the link unfortunately it's not working for me. For the moment, I no longer require the use of WCSF. I guess there's always the full proof method of nuking the whole system and reinstalling :)